# ColorFiltered Overflows Image

Tags: flutter, image, image-processing, filter, colorfilter

So I am currently trying to change the color of an image with `ColorFilter.mode(Colors.green, BlendMode.hue)`.

But the filter affects the image behind too and the `Container`. What I would like to have would be a mix of `BlendMode.srcIn` and `BlendMode.hue`.

I need the Image edited not a make the Container white solution :/

Help would be appreciated :/

```dart
Container(
  color: Colors.white,
  child: ColorFiltered(
    colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(Colors.green, BlendMode.hue),
    child: Image.asset('assets/eyes/$eyes.png'),
  ),
),
```

I would like to have the Image 1 turned into the Eyes of 2 without the green background. (The eyes of Image 1 have a transparent background)

| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [image: eye] | [image: eye] | [image: eye] |

Comment: check https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Image/Image.asset.html

Comment: What exactly do you mean which parameter should I check @pskink

Comment: color / blend mode related?

Comment: I already tried putting blendMode.srcIn for Image.asset() and hue for ColorFiltered that didn’t work@pskink

Comment: ok, post the source image (with transparency if it has any transparent pixels) and the exact result you want to achieve

Comment: I improved the question so 1 is the source and the eyes of two are what I want without the green background of course @pskink

Comment: @pskink I could really use some help it would mean the world to me. :/

Answer (score 2):

Apply a **ColorFilter** to an **Image** without affecting the background Container. To achieve this effect, you can wrap your `Image.asset` **widget** with a `ClipRect` **widget**. The `ClipRect` will constrain the effect of the `ColorFilter` to only affect its **child**, which is the **Image**.

```
Container(
  color: Colors.white,
  child: ClipRect(
    child: ColorFiltered(
      colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(Colors.green, BlendMode.hue),
      child: Image.asset('assets/eyes/$eyes.png'),
    ),
  ),
),
```

Comment: Doesn’t work at all